# React Form: How to add error message that disappear if the input was typed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already built the form in React and it shows the input fields in red borders that'll change to regular borders once someone types it in. I used this example from this [React form article link](https://goshakkk.name/instant-form-fields-validation-react/) So everything is working except I wanted to add the error message under the input field that displays "Please fill in the blank field" that will disappear once someone starts typing in the field. How do I do this?

Here's my code in Form.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormField from './FormFieldBox';

function validate(name, isin) {
  // true means invalid, so our conditions got reversed
  return {
    name: name.length === 0,
    isin: isin.length === 0
  };
}

export default class PopupForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      isin: '',
      country: '',
      errormessage: ''
    }
  }

  updateInput = (e) =>{
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  closePopupSubmit = (e) => {
    if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    let security = {     //1.gather security data from form submit
      name: this.state.name,
      isin: this.state.isin,
      country: this.state.country
     } 
     this.props.submitPopup(security); //2.closePopup function, add security data
  }
  canBeSubmitted() {
    const errors = validate(this.state.name, this.state.isin);
    const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
    return !isDisabled;
  }

  cancelPopupSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
     this.props.cancelPopup();
  }

  render() {
    const errors = validate(this.state.name, this.state.isin);
    const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
    return (
      <div className='popup'>  
      <div className='popup-inner'>  
      <form onSubmit={this.closePopupSubmit}>
        <FormField onChange={this.updateInput} className={errors.name ? "input error" : "input"} label="Name" type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} />
        <FormField onChange={this.updateInput} className={errors.isin ? "input error" : "input"} label="ISIN" type="text" name="isin" value={this.state.isin} />
        <FormField onChange={this.updateInput} label="Country" type="text" name="country" value={this.state.country} />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.cancelPopupSubmit} className="button">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" className="button" disabled={isDisabled}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      </div>  
      </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

And my component FormField.js

```
import React from "react";

const FormBox = props => {
  return (
    <div className="field">
      <label className="label">{props.label}</label>
      <div className="control">
        <input onChange={props.onChange}
          className={props.className}
          type={props.type}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder} />
          {/* {props.errormessage} */}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FormBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const FormBox = props => {
  return (
    <div className="field">
      <label className="label">{props.label}</label>
      <div className="control">
        <input onChange={props.onChange}
          className={props.className}
          type={props.type}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder} />
      </div>
      {Boolean(props.value.length) || (
        <div className="err-msg">
          Please fill in the blank field
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this

First : oninvalid attribute in HTML5 and calling a custom function on that.

Second : along with each element name object  in state have a length attribute. In validation function you can check for the length and throw a custom error that you want to display.